# ARCore: The application does not have permission to use the Tango 'Dataset Read/Write' capabilities

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-project-tango, arcore

Im am getting the following error when attempting to implement a native plugin in Unity. I have this plugin working in both a standalone Android application as well as a VR implementation so I think this is a specific ARCore permission issue. I am not familiar with how Tango is implemented with regard to ARCore:

> W/tango: permission_handler.cc:76 The application
>   'com.midtablestudios.'ApplicationName'' does not have permission to
>   use the Tango 'Dataset Read/Write' capabilities. To ask the user of
>   your app for this permission, invoke the Tango Android permissions
>   intent for 'Dataset Read/Write'.

Comment: What is your Unity version?

Comment: I'm on Unity 2017.2.0f3.

Comment: Was this with [Developer Preview 2 (released last Friday)](https://blog.google/products/google-vr/arcore-developer-preview-2/)?  If not, try upgrading (will require updating Unity as well I think).

Comment: Yes @IanM I spent most of today tinkering with Preview 2 and the new Beta. I posted an answer with what the problem was and how to request permissions in preview 2. Hopefully it helps the next person.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like this was a permission issue with Preview 1 (see image). It appears that that it would only grant the first permission in the permissions array (odd!) and since the camera is required for ARCore, that's the only permission you could register. Preview 2 lets you pass permissions as strings directly without this array setup.

ex:  AndroidPermissionsManager.RequestPermission("android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE")

[AndroidPermissionManager.cs_ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSjg1.png)